# How do I set a default cache-control for for new images uploaded to buckets on google storage

Tags: google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-platform, gsutil

I know that you can run a command at upload to set the cache-control of the image being uploaded

```
gsutil -h "Cache-Control:public,max-age=2628000" cp -a public-read \\
   -r html gs://bucket
```

But I'm using carrierwave in rails and don't think its possible to set it up to run this command each time an image is uploaded.

I was looking around to see if you can change the default cache-control number but cant find any solutions. Currently I run `gsutil -m setmeta -h "Cache-Control:public, max-age=2628000" gs://bucket/*.png` every now and then to update new images but this is a horrible solution.

Any ideas on how to set the default cache-control for files uploaded to a bucket?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no way to set a default Cache-Control header on newly uploaded files. It either needs to be set explicitly (by setting the header) at the time the object is written, or after the upload by updating the object's metadata using something like the gsutil command you noted.